# how to perform histogram on numpy array whose dtype is object using histogramdd?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, python-datetime, multidimensional-array

I want to perform histogram on a `(N, 3) numpy array`, whose three dimensions represent longitude, latitude and time-stamp correspondingly, like this:

```
array([[116.45565032958984, 39.889976501464844,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 32, 39)],
       [116.45565032958984, 39.889984130859375,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 31)],
       [116.45565032958984, 39.889984130859375,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 33)],
       [116.45565032958984, 39.889984130859375,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 37)],
       [116.45561981201172, 39.89040756225586,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 34, 42)],
       [116.45561981201172, 39.890411376953125,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 36, 40)],
       [116.45549774169922, 39.8941650390625,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 37, 54)],
       [116.45556640625, 39.92431640625,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 38, 57)],
       [116.45578002929688, 39.93780517578125,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 42, 10)],
       [116.44468688964844, 39.93989944458008,
        datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 43, 21)]], dtype=object)
```

I tried to use `np.histogramdd` like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.histogramdd(my_data, bins = (lon_bin_num, lat_bin_num, time_bin_num), 
                range = [[lon_min, lon_max], [lat_min, lat_max], 
                [start_datetime, end_datetime]])
```

And got `TypeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-58c94eecf21d> in <module>()
      1 np.histogramdd(tmp2, bins = (lon_bin_num, lat_bin_num, time_bin_num),
----> 2                range = [[lon_min, lon_max], [lat_min, lat_max], [start_datetime, end_datetime]])

/*/*/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in histogramdd(sample, bins, range, normed, weights)
    318         smax = zeros(D)
    319         for i in arange(D):
--> 320             smin[i], smax[i] = range[i]
    321 
    322     # Make sure the bins have a finite width.

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I know it was the datetime object causing the error, but I want to know how to correct this error or how to perform histogram on numpy ndarray whose `dtype = object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of NumPy functions do not work with arrays of dtype `object`. To use `np.histogramdd`, you'll need an array of shape `(N, D)`, so structured arrays will not be helpful here either (since a structured array would remove the `D` dimension). You'll need an array of *homogenous* non-object dtype. Since the first two columns are floats, let's try to represent the third column as floats too:

You could convert the dates into NumPy's native `datetime64[s]` dtype:

```
In [102]: dates = np.array(my_data[:, 2],dtype='<M8[s]')

In [103]: dates
Out[103]: 
array(['2012-10-01T02:32:39-0400', '2012-10-01T02:33:31-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:33:33-0400', '2012-10-01T02:33:37-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:34:42-0400', '2012-10-01T02:36:40-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:37:54-0400', '2012-10-01T02:38:57-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:42:10-0400', '2012-10-01T02:43:21-0400'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

and then use `astype` to convert those `datetime64[s]`s into `float`s:

```
In [104]: float_dates = dates.astype('float')

In [105]: float_dates
Out[105]: 
array([  1.34907316e+09,   1.34907321e+09,   1.34907321e+09,
         1.34907322e+09,   1.34907328e+09,   1.34907340e+09,
         1.34907347e+09,   1.34907354e+09,   1.34907373e+09,
         1.34907380e+09])
```

Now form a new array with dtype `float`:

```
arr = np.empty_like(my_data, dtype='float')
arr[:, 0:2] = my_data[:, 0:2]
arr[:, 2] = float_dates

hist, edges = np.histogramdd(arr, bins=(xedges, yedges, zedges))
```

While this will give you a histogram, you may also need to re-interpret the floats as dates. You can do that with `astype`. To obtain `datetime64[s]`:

```
In [99]: float_dates.astype('<M8[s]')
Out[99]: 
array(['2012-10-01T02:32:39-0400', '2012-10-01T02:33:31-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:33:33-0400', '2012-10-01T02:33:37-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:34:42-0400', '2012-10-01T02:36:40-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:37:54-0400', '2012-10-01T02:38:57-0400',
       '2012-10-01T02:42:10-0400', '2012-10-01T02:43:21-0400'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

To obtain Python `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
In [116]: float_dates.astype('<M8[s]').tolist()
Out[116]: 
[datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 32, 39),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 31),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 33),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 33, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 34, 42),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 36, 40),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 37, 54),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 38, 57),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 42, 10),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 6, 43, 21)]
```